# Argument Exception Was Unhandled

Tags: c#

here is my code on form1.

```
private void flopCards()//view the 2 face down card
{
    string hold1=NumGen.CardGenerator(i)
        ,hold2=NumGen.CardGenerator(i)
    ,hold4=NumGen.CardGenerator(i)
    ,hold5=NumGen.CardGenerator(i);
    holder1.Image = Image.FromFile(hold1, true);
    holder2.Image = Image.FromFile(hold2, true);

}    

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Controls.Remove(button1);
    player();
    bot1();
    GrpBx();
    Get3rd.Click += new EventHandler(Get3rd_Click);
    check.Click += new EventHandler(check_Click);
}

void check_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    flopCards();
}
```

what i want to accomplish is when i click the check button I the picture of the holders will be replaced with a card.. there where no error shown at the error list but when i try to run and click the button what i get is an popup where it said"argument exception was unhandled the path is not of a legal form"

please help me!

Comment: Sounds like your program is unable to find the file on your hard drive. What's the value of the "hold1" string when you pass it to Image.FromFile()? Chances are it's not a valid path.

Comment: the file is located on the same folder of the project.

Comment: There is something you are saying that makes me believe you should read more on the bare basics of programmation. You say "there are no error shown on the error list" - but the error list you're mentionning basically makes sure that your syntax is correct. It doesn't mean that your application will run once you compile it. They are two very separate thing.

Comment: Otherwise, I asked you a very specific question. "What is the value of `Hold1` string when you pass it to Image.FromFile()?" - if you cannot answer that question, you definitely need to get a basic book or tutorial on programmation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string hold1=NumGen.CardGenerator(i);
try
{
    if (File.Exists(hold1))
        Console.WriteLine("The file {0} was found.", hold1);
    else
        Console.WriteLine("Error: The file {0} cannot be found", hold1);
}
catch (ArgumentException ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("I don't understand the path you supplied.");
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
}
```

Run your program and check the output window. Hopefully it will help you understand why you can't access your image.

Comment: the file.exists code is not working on my program... im using windows.forms btw

Comment: Winforms doesn't have anything to do with this. If you cannot find File.Exists, add "using System.IO;" to the top of your class file.